# How can I convert binary data received from C++ client socket to python Server socket

Tags: python, c++, sockets, buffer, ascii

I am trying to decode bytes received from human readable form. If I use `decode('utf-8')` python gives error

> utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 257-258: invalid continuation byte

If I use `decode('iso-8859-1')` it shows garbage values

```
***�1234567 "PROTOCOL-ICMP Address Mask Request undefined code"¸y»_Äý
                                                         bb"*
                                                             )#FªPVúEÀ¨~`v¸y»_Iw
                                                                               �**
```

**python code:** `udpUnixServer.py`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import os, os.path
import struct

if os.path.exists("snort_alert"):
  os.remove("snort_alert")

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM,0)

server.bind("snort_alert")

while True:
  print("listening")
  datagram,addr = server.recvfrom(1024)
  print(datagram)
  print("Unpack")
  print(struct.unpack_from('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssl', datagram, 0))
  #x=bytearray(datagram) 
  #print(x)


server.close()

os.remove("snort_alert")

print("Done")
```

Output without decoding:

```
b'"PROTOCOL-ICMP Address Mask Request undefined code"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x12\xbe_\x9a\xb8\n\x00b\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00PV\xfa\x82\xe2\x00\x0c)#F\xaa\x08\x00E\x00\x00T#p@\x00@\x01\xd4\x07\xc0\xa8~\x83\x01\x02\x03\x04\x08\x00z\x1a\x00\x0c\x1b\xdc[\x12\xbe_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xb8\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./01234567\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I am not sure how to use `struct.pack` or `struct.unpack` to convert above bytes into string.

Please guide.

Comment: In your datagram you have zeroes after the string "PROTOCOL-ICMP Address Mask Request undefined code". What do you want to do with them?

Comment: Because using your data you can simply do `str(data[1:50])[2:-1]` to drop the trailing zeroes and print it as human readable string without "b" prefix (result: 'PROTOCOL-ICMP Address Mask Request undefined code'). Sorry for hardcoded indices

Comment: @pptaszni I want to decode these machine bytes.

Comment: Great, but in your 1024 bytes of data most of it are zeroes. How do you want to treat those zeroes (in ASCII it is NULL, obviously)? Also, why are you sending so many zeroes from your C++ socket?

Comment: @pptaszni I have snort IDS which is sending attack data to python socket. Below is C++ struct:

struct Alertpkt
{
    uint8_t alertmsg[256]; 
    struct pcap_pkthdr32 pkth;
    uint32_t dlthdr;      
    uint32_t nethdr;      
    uint32_t transhdr;    
    uint32_t data;
    uint32_t val; 
#define NOPACKET_STRUCT 0x1

#define NO_TRANSHDR    0x2
    uint8_t pkt[65535];     
    uint32_t gid;
    uint32_t sid;
    uint32_t rev;
    uint32_t class_id;
    uint32_t priority;

    uint32_t event_id;
    uint32_t event_ref;
    struct sf_timeval32 ref_time;
};

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at your struct. Your `struct Alertpkt` is 65864 bytes, mostly because of very big `uint8_t pkt[65535];` array. Also only first 256 bytes in `uint8_t alertmsg[256];` probably represent a string (not necessarily 256 bytes long, can be shorter).

```
struct sf_timeval32
{
    uint32_t tv_sec;
    uint32_t tv_usec;
};

struct pcap_pkthdr32
{
    struct sf_timeval32 ts;
    uint32_t caplen;
    uint32_t pktlen;
};

struct Alertpkt
{
  uint8_t alertmsg[256];
  struct pcap_pkthdr32 pkth;
  uint32_t dlthdr;
  uint32_t nethdr;
  uint32_t transhdr;
  uint32_t data;
  uint32_t val;
  #define NOPACKET_STRUCT 0x1
  #define NO_TRANSHDR 0x2
  uint8_t pkt[65535];
  uint32_t gid;
  uint32_t sid;
  uint32_t rev;
  uint32_t class_id;
  uint32_t priority;
  uint32_t event_id;
  uint32_t event_ref;
  struct sf_timeval32 ref_time;
};
```

In your example data that you received on Python side (only 1024 bytes)

```
>>> datagram[0:51]
b'"PROTOCOL-ICMP Address Mask Request undefined code"'
```

represents human readable message that you got and you can treat it like Python string. Then `datagram[51:256]` are just padding zeroes and you should skip them.

Next 16 bytes

```
>>> datagram[256:256+16]
b'[\x12\xbe_\x9a\xb8\n\x00b\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x0
```

are: `tv_sec`, `tv_usec`, `caplen`, `pktlen`. All of then are 4-bytes unsigned integers, so you can read their values e.g. with:

```
>>> ctypes.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(datagram[256:256+4])
c_uint(1606292059)
>>> ctypes.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(datagram[256+4:256+8])
c_uint(702618)
>>> ctypes.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(datagram[256+8:256+12])
c_uint(98)
>>> ctypes.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(datagram[256+12:256+16])
c_uint(98)
```

and so on for the remaining part of the data ... I think the values are reasonable, because `tv_sec` represents epoch value of "Wednesday, November 25, 2020 8:14:19 AM". Just have in mind that 1024 bytes is not a whole structure. Also probably you should define the offsets, or write a nice decoding function, instead of using magic numbers directly.